# Python Nested Loops To Print Rectangle With Asterisks

Tags: python, nested-loops

Write nested loops to print a rectangle. Sample output for given program:

3 stars   :   ***

3 stars   :   ***

I tried it and ended up with this:

```
num_rows = 2

num_cols = 3

'''IDK WHAT TO PUT HERE'''
    print('*', end=' ')
print('')
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Pretty sure you must have some course notes about [control constructs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go! Try this!

```
num_rows = 2
num_cols = 3

for i in range(num_rows):
    print('*', end=' ')
    for j in range(num_cols-1):
        i*=j
        print('*', end=' ')
    print('')
```

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to learn, I think, so a here is a hint to push you in the right direction.

You need to use a nested `for` loop. Use the [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) builtin to produce an iterable sequence.

The outer for loop should iterate over the number of rows. The inner (nested) for loop should iterate over the columns.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for resurrecting this thread, but i'm going through the same Zybooks course and the answer is actually a lot simpler than what was voted correct here.

```
num_rows = 2
num_cols = 3
for i in range(num_rows):
    for i in range(num_cols):
        print('*', end=' ')
    print()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the 
num_rows = 2
num_cols = 3
It will limit it to the correct variables if you are using zybooks

Answer (score 0):

I just recently came across this in a exam I had, here is another way.

```
for i in range(0,9,1):
    for i in range(0,21,1):
        print('X', end='')
    print()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

num_rows = int(input())
num_cols = int(input())

for i in range(num_rows):
print('*', end=' ')
for j in range(num_cols-1):
i*=j
print('*', end=' ')
print()

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).